# Admin email is not updating on Drupal7

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal-7, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, drupal-database

I have tried to install Drupal 7.x on AWS by using cloudformation but after the installation, while connecting to the RDS admin the administrator email is not updating.

In the `users` table,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIfMa.png) I am able to find all the schema that I have given while installing the Drupal site except for `mail(Default)`. The `mail` field is filled up with `"admin@example.com"`, and I am unable to find my email in the table. Due to this result, am unable to reset my password and also create new users. New users also don't receive emails from the admin.

I am able to see my email in the Drupal site but in the database, I see `"admin@example.com"` (the default value). What could be going wrong here?

Comment: You are mixing two different things, the site information section is NOT admin mail address. It's your site's "from"  address when you send emails and it's located in "variables" table under the "site_mail". To change email address for admin you need to go on profile yoursite.com/user/1/edit  that email address is in users table which are you referring to.

Comment: Thanks for the information.i can able to change admin email from .com/user/1/ but new users did not receive an email fro admin.

Comment: they receive welcome emails from "site_address" not from admin's address. I'm not sure where the problem is can you be more specific?

Comment: Currently, I'm able to install Drupal site but I'm trying to create to new users I did not receive from any email from Drupal site to log in as the user even though after I'm activating user from my admin panel but I couldn't receive any email to new user's registered email..

Comment: Your mail server is not working mate you need to set up mail server in order to send emails in a first place. Nothing to do with "from" address.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the information.